# Converting SQL statement to Active Record syntax

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm having some trouble figuring out the Active Record syntax for the following Postgres query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tracks
JOIN displays on displays.track_id = tracks.id
JOIN users on displays.user_id = users.id
WHERE user_id = 1
  AND displays.display is true
  AND tracks.likes_count > 200
```

The above query above works, and now I'm trying to convert it to activerecord's syntax but getting the error:

> PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'t'" LINE 1:
>   ...ck_id" = "tracks"."id" WHERE (displays.display is 't', track...

```
Track.joins(:users, :displays).where('displays.display is ?, tracks.likes_count > ?, users.id = ?', true, 200, 1)
```

It seems like I'm doing something wrong with the `displays.display is True` statement, but I have tried a few variations to no avail.

I'm using Activerecord-4.2.0.

I would appreciate some insight.

Comment: `is [not] true` and `is [not] false` are considered to be suffix operators (or somewhat like that, with special syntax). you cannot parameterize the `true`/`false` part of them. If the `display` column cannot be `NULL`, you could use `displays.display = ?`.

Comment: I see, you can't parameterize a boolean....how can I parametrize the other fields and still set the boolean? I've tried a few different variations that you suggested but no luck.

Comment: no, you can (in general) pass a boolean parameter, but your case (`is true`) is special.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I was actually just missing the ANDs....derp:

```
Track.joins(:users, :displays).where('displays.display = ? AND tracks.likes_count > ? AND users.id = ? ', true, 200, 1)
```

**UPDATE** Also as @Andrius pointed out Track.joins(:users, :displays) and Track.joins(:displays => :users) are two different joins and I want to use the former.

Answer (score 0):

By default ActiveRecord doesn't know how to join tracks and users, so indicate that you want to join through the displays:

```
Track.joins(:displays => :users).where('displays.display is true, tracks.likes_count > ?, users.id = ?', 200, 1)
```

Hope I remember syntax well :)

Comment: Isn't that example what I'm doing here `Track.joins(:users, :displays)`

Comment: `Track.joins(:users, :displays)` and `Track.joins(:displays => :users)` are two different joins. In the first case both inner joins use `Track` as the reference and in the second case the first inner join takes `Track` into account, but the second inner join is only between `displays` and `users`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the joins, you can try this:

```
Track.joins(displays: :users).where('displays.display = ?, tracks.likes_count > ?, users.id = ?', true, 200, 1)
```

You can make a join with a third table using the syntax:

Table1.joins(table2: :table3)

Result:

```
SELECT "table1".* 
 FROM "table1" 
 INNER JOIN "table2" ON "table2"."table_id" = "table1"."table1_id" 
 INNER JOIN "table3" ON "table3"."table2_id" = "table2"."table2_id"
```

able3" ON "table3"."table2_id" = "table2"."table2_id"

You can read more for ActiveRecord's joins method here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: I thought that is exactly what I'm doing here: `Track.joins(:users, :displays)`